# TSLint get rid of missing-whitespace

Tags: typescript, tslint

I've been trying to scour the internet to solve this but to no avail. Perhaps you can help me. I am getting tslint 'missing whitespace' warnings that say something like:

WARNING in ./src/app/content/content.controller.ts
[4, 13]: missing whitespace
[5, 21]: missing whitespace

I want to get rid of the warning

Here's an example of the code.... basically anywhere I have a colon for declaring type is where the error is happening. I don't want to put a space between it so I'd like the linter to not bug me about it...

```
export class ContentCtrl {
filters:IFilter[];
selectedFilters:IFilter[];
filterToAdd:IFilter;

/** @ngInject */
constructor(private $log:angular.ILogService,
            private $timeout:any,
            private toastr:any,
            private filterService:FilterService) {
    const self = this;
```

I looked through the tslint.json file and could not figure out how to get rid of it.

I saw a promising property that said: "typedef-whitespace"

I changed it to the following but, alas, to no-avail:

```
"typedef-whitespace": [true,
        {
            "callSignature": "noSpace",
            "catchClause": "noSpace",
            "indexSignature": "noSpace",
            "parameter": "noSpace"
        }
    ],
```

How do I get rid of the 'missing whitespace' error?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This error message comes from the [whitespace rule](http://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/whitespace/). I believe the rule wants you to add a space either before or after (not sure which) the colon in type declarations. However, if you don't like this, you can disable the rule completely, or remove the `check-type` option from your `tslint.json` file.

Comment: Removing check-type did the job. Cheers!

Comment: add space before colon :
Use code format. In IntelliJ use ctrl + alt + L

Comment: I added this line "whitespace": false, to my tslint.json, but unlike other entries, it appears to have no effect in turned off validation for this rule. What am I missing?

Answer (score 14):

You should search `whitespace` in `tslint.json`,and replace all result whith `false`.

And you questions can set like there:

```
"whitespace": [
  false,
  "check-branch",
  "check-decl",
  "check-operator",
  "check-separator",
  "check-type"
],
```

set it ,if you write **private nima:string**, : with no space will no err.

---

other,

if you set `one-line` 's metadata to `false`,the class can  follow no space.

if yout set `no-trailing-whitespace` to `false`, the line can use tab.

——end

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Yue Ming. Please don't use Chinese characters here. This is an English-only website. We would appreciate if you could edit your post to avoid encoding issues in Western countries... Thanks! ;)

Answer (score 2):

What TSLint seems to be complaining about are the class property declarations, so maybe try adding this extra rule to "typedef-whitespace":

```
"property-declaration": "nospace",
```

You can find more about that rule [here](http://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/typedef-whitespace/).

Comment: It's a good idea but it didn't work in my case. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

This lint error message prompts that you need to give a space between particular characters in your code.
For example,
`ERROR: 58:18  whitespace   missing whitespace`
means, In line 58, you need to provide space after the 18th position in your code snippet.