# Remove some tslint rules

Tags: angular, tslint

I need to remove below tslint rules from my tslint.json.

1. file should end with a newline
2. trailing whitespace
3. missing whitespace
4. " should be '

In order to remove white-spaces, I removed `check-type` by looking at this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35489086/tslint-get-rid-of-missing-whitespace).

But still I'm getting errors when I run `ng lint` command on cli. Anyone knows how to remove above rules from my tslint.json file ?

tslint.json

```
    {
  "rulesDirectory": [
    "node_modules/codelyzer"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "arrow-return-shorthand": true,
    "callable-types": true,
    "class-name": true,
    "comment-format": [
      false,
      "check-space"
    ],
    "curly": true,
    "eofline": true,
    "forin": true,
    "import-blacklist": [
      true,
      "rxjs",
      "rxjs/Rx"
    ],
    "import-spacing": true,
    "indent": [
      false,
      "spaces"
    ],
    "interface-over-type-literal": true,
    "label-position": true,
    "max-line-length": [
      true,
      200
    ],
    "member-access": false,
    "member-ordering": [
      true,
      {
        "order": [
          "static-field",
          "instance-field",
          "static-method",
          "instance-method"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "no-arg": true,
    "no-bitwise": true,
    "no-console": [
      true,
      "debug",
      "info",
      "time",
      "timeEnd",
      "trace"
    ],
    "no-construct": true,
    "no-debugger": true,
    "no-duplicate-super": true,
    "no-empty": false,
    "no-empty-interface": true,
    "no-eval": true,
    "no-inferrable-types": [
      true,
      "ignore-params"
    ],
    "no-misused-new": true,
    "no-non-null-assertion": true,
    "no-shadowed-variable": true,
    "no-string-literal": false,
    "no-string-throw": true,
    "no-switch-case-fall-through": true,
    "no-trailing-whitespace": true,
    "no-unnecessary-initializer": true,
    "no-unused-expression": true,
    "no-use-before-declare": true,
    "no-var-keyword": true,
    "object-literal-sort-keys": false,
    "one-line": [
      true,
      "check-open-brace",
      "check-catch",
      "check-else",
      "check-whitespace"
    ],
    "prefer-const": true,
    "quotemark": [
      true,
      "single"
    ],
    "radix": true,
    "semicolon": [
      true,
      "always"
    ],
    "triple-equals": [
      true,
      "allow-null-check"
    ],
    "typedef-whitespace": [
      true,
      {
        "call-signature": "nospace",
        "index-signature": "nospace",
        "parameter": "nospace",
        "property-declaration": "nospace",
        "variable-declaration": "nospace"
      }
    ],
    "typeof-compare": true,
    "unified-signatures": true,
    "variable-name": false,
    "whitespace": [
      false,
      "check-branch",
      "check-decl",
      "check-operator",
      "check-separator",
      "check-type"
    ],
    "directive-selector": [
      true,
      "attribute",
      "app",
      "camelCase"
    ],
    "component-selector": [
      true,
      "element",
      "app",
      "kebab-case"
    ],
    "use-input-property-decorator": true,
    "use-output-property-decorator": true,
    "use-host-property-decorator": true,
    "no-input-rename": true,
    "no-output-rename": true,
    "use-life-cycle-interface": true,
    "use-pipe-transform-interface": true,
    "component-class-suffix": true,
    "directive-class-suffix": true,
    "invoke-injectable": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove in your tsLint :

`"no-trailing-whitespace": true,`

`"whitespace": [
      false,
      "check-branch",
      "check-decl",
      "check-operator",
      "check-separator",
      "check-type"
    ],`

`"quotemark": [
      true,
      "single"
    ],`

`"eofline": true,`

Comment: What if I set those to false ?

Comment: You can do it also. But the easiest thing is to try :)

Answer (score 1):

1.file should end with a new line

```
"eofline": true,
```

2.trailing whitespace

```
"no-trailing-whitespace": false,
```

3.Missing Whitespace

```
"whitespace": [
  false,
  "check-branch",
  "check-decl",
  "check-operator",
  "check-separator",
  "check-type"
],
```

4." should be '

```
"quotemark": [
  true,
  "single"
],
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I do it in my root folder where my tslint.json file is:

But first change `"no-trailing-whitespace": true`, to `false` in tslint.json

tslint only warns you. Prettier enforces it. You might want to check out the prettier docs. It took me a while to fine tune mine. Now I just use it in everyone of my application across the board.

1. In my `.editorconfig` file I have the following which comes with every new Angular app:

> ```
> # Editor configuration, see http://editorconfig.org
> root = true
>
> [*]
> charset = utf-8
> indent_style = space
> indent_size = 2
> insert_final_newline = true
> trim_trailing_whitespace = true
>
> [*.md]
> max_line_length = off
> trim_trailing_whitespace = false
> ```

2. Use prettier. With a .prettierrc file:

> ```
> {
>   "arrowParens": "avoid",
>   "bracketSpacing": true,
>   "endOfLine": "auto",
>   "htmlWhitespaceSensitivity": "strict",
>   "semi": true,
>   "singleQuote": true,
>   "tabWidth": 2,
>   "trailingComma": "all",
>   "useTabs": false
> }
> ```

3. In folder `vscode` in `extensions.json` (with this whenever you start vs code it will prompt you to install the recommendation:

> ```
> // See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=827846 to learn about workspace recommendations.
> // Extension identifier format: ${publisher}.${name}. Example: vscode.csharp
>
> // List of extensions which should be recommended for users of this workspace.
> {
>   "recommendations": [
>     "Angular.ng-template",
>     "DavidAnson.vscode-markdownlint",
>     "eamodio.gitlens",
>     "EditorConfig.EditorConfig",
>     "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
>     "mike-co.import-sorter",
>     "ms-vscode.vscode-typescript-tslint-plugin"
>   ],
>   "unwantedRecommendations": [
>     "amatiasq.sort-imports",
>     "eg2.tslint",
>     "HookyQR.beautify"
>   ]
> }
> ```

4. `package.json` add these then do `npm install`:

> ```
> "prettier": "1.18.2",
> "protractor": "5.4.2",
> "tslint-config-prettier": "1.18.0",
> "tslint-consistent-codestyle": "1.16.0",
> "tslint-plugin-prettier": "2.0.1",
> ```

5. In tslint.json (using the following, if you don't add #4 above you will get a warning that they are missing and the annoying yellow code underlines:

> ```
> {
>   "defaultSeverity": "error",
>   "extends": [
>     "tslint:latest",
>     "tslint-config-prettier",
>     "tslint-consistent-codestyle"
>   ],
>   "rules": {...
> ```